# FuelSDK connection error

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#, fuel-sdk

I'm getting this error below, any ideas? Thanks!

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 50.18.179.4:443

Exception thrown from line 127 in `refreshToken()` method in `ET_Client.cs`.

> `string json;`
>   `using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter( request.GetRequestStream() )) {`

Networking guys said it isn't connection through proxy and should be.

[SocketException (0x274d): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 50.18.179.4:443]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +208
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +464

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) +6541489
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() +13
   FuelSDK.ET_Client.refreshToken(Boolean force) +341
   FuelSDK.ET_Client..ctor(NameValueCollection parameters) +2035
   TheDreamProject._default.btnSubscribe_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\FuelSDK-CSharp-Dot9.zip\FuelSDK-CSharp-Dot9\TheDreamProject\TheDreamProject\default.aspx.cs:30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9633194
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe your error is related to the SDK.  These may help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096657/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0

Comment: It was issue with how our internal network handles SSL connections. Running Fiddler fixed the issue.

Comment: OK, so when I connect from outside my company network, I'm able to get the connection. So this brings us to the next question. Am I able to configure a proxy in FuelSdk or do I need a firewall hole? If a firewall hole, what port?

Comment: Can you post the line of code receiving this error so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: added code, think `HttpWebRequest request` needs to use corporate proxy.